# Relating table data using code first approach

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

How to relate the data in following scenario:
Ninja -> NinjaItem -> ItemList
So that NinjaItem-table would contain data of the items belonging to the Ninja? ItemList-table should contain only item-name and id.

I have the following that relates the Ninja to NinjaItem but I cannot figure out how to relate also NinjaItem to ItemList.

```
public class Ninja
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<NinjaItem> NinjaItem { get; set; }
}
public class NinjaItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int NinjaID { get; set; }
    public int ItemListID { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ItemList> ItemList{ get; set; }
}
public class ItemList
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }      
}
```

Comment: Consider searching for Entity Framework many to many relationships.

Comment: Thank you. didn't understand my problem first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved solution from question to answer:

> **SOLUTION:**
>   I only needed two classes Ninja and ItemList and Entity Framework creates the third table linking items to ninjas.
>
> ```
> public class Ninja
> {
>     public Ninja ()
>     {
>         this.ItemLists = new HashSet<ItemList>();
>     }
>     public int NinjaId { get; set; }
>     public string Name { get; set; }
>     public virtual ICollection<ItemList> ItemLists { get; set; }
> }
>
> public class ItemList
> {
>     public ItemList ()
>     {
>         this.Ninjas = new HashSet<Ninja>();
>     }
>     public int ItemListId { get; set; }
>     public string ItemName { get; set; }
>     public virtual ICollection<Ninja> Ninjas { get; set; }
>
> }
> ```